# Requiring a checkbox is checked using CheckBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I need to have a checkbox (for agreeing to terms) required on an MVC3 page.

Here is my model:

```
[Required]
[Display("I agree to the terms.")]
public bool Agreement { get; set; }
```

Here is my view:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Agreement)
```

However, the validation isn't happening -- it allows the form to be submitted regardless.

I found that CheckBoxFor renders an additional hidden field, but I even tried rendering my own checkbox, and it still isn't getting validated:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Agreement" id="Agreement" value="true" data-val="true"
    data-val-required="You must agree to the terms before proceeding." />
```

What am I doing wrong?